# Can you explain the syntax: "pd.index.str.lower().str.contains()"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I provided the following command.

```
import pandas as pd

movies=pd.read_csv(r'E:\movies.csv', index_col="Title")
movies_with_dark=movies.index.str.lower().str.contains("dark")
movies[movies_with_dark]
```

The result was, a DataFrame containing all films with the keyword "dark"

Can somebody explain to me the syntax, `pd.index.str.lower().str.contains()`
Especially, why the `str` method again, after the `lower()`?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your index contains strings with the names of movies.

```
# access the index
movies.index

# make index strings lowercase
movies.index.str.lower()

# check if each string contains the word "dark"
movies.index.str.lower().str.contains("dark")
# one could also use
movies.index.str.contains("dark", case=False)
```

The above returns a Series of booleans that is assigned to a variable and use to slice the original data with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
movies_with_dark=movies.index.str.lower().str.contains("dark")
movies[movies_with_dark]
```

Example input:

```
                 col
The Dark Movie     A
another darkness   B
something else     C
```

Intermediates (as columns for clarity):

```
                 col             index         str.lower  str.contains("dark")
The Dark Movie     A    The Dark Movie    the dark movie                  True
another darkness   B  another darkness  another darkness                  True
something else     C    something else    something else                 False
```

Output:

```
                 col
The Dark Movie     A
another darkness   B
```

Comment: I'm confused why `movies.index.str` isn't a string, which would make `movies.index.str.lower().str` an attribute error, surely

Comment: @JackDeeth because [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) is **not a string** (nor converting to string) but an accessor towards multiple string related functions, among which `str.lower` that converts to lower in a **vectorial way** (i.e. returning a Series).

Comment: @mosway thank you so much for this wonderful explanation! I have now understood what the syntax does.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read [working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['Dark Movie', 'Another'], 'Budget': [1, 2]}).set_index(['Movie'])

print(df.index.str.lower())
```

returns an index object which doesn't have a contains method.

```
Index(['dark movie', 'another'], dtype='object', name='Movie')
```

the index object does however have a [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) method which lets  you access vectorized string methods, hence the second contains method.

If you are interested, a believe the StringMethods object is defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L150).